# Convert MYSQL query returned to JSON with 3rd dimension in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have query that returns number of rows with the following format

```
Array ( [speaker_id] => 47 [firstname] => Sunil [lastname] => Badve **[TLL] => Greg,Sharon** )
 Array ( [speaker_id] => 87 [firstname] => Menal [lastname] => lal **[TLL] => JOHN,Brandi** )
```

I want result in the following JSON format

```
{
speaker_id : 47,
firstname : Sunil,
lastname : Badve,
**TLL : [{Greg},{Sharon}]**
}
{
 speaker_id : 87,
 firstname : Mehal,
 lastname : lal,
 **TLL : [{JOHN},{Brandi}]**
 }
```

I am stuck at the TLL part, I dont know how to assign it to JSON with separate item. I am using PHP to do json encoding.

Comment: I got idea to use explode function to separate each element and assign them.

Comment: `json_encode()` maybe ?